# In the GWT (HTML) module using libGDX, the HTTPResponse is returned as null

Tags: gwt, libgdx, cors

Using LibGDX, I am creating an HTTP request.
This works well on Android, iOS and Desktop, however on GWT (HTML) the returns HTTPResponse is empty.
In developer mode in Chrome I see:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have looked around and understand it is to do with Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) but have been unable so far to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Having reviewed the entries by other people with the same issue (e.g.: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/1433) I managed to solve the issue.

The point is that this is not something you can solve on your LibGDX implementation. It is something you need to configure on your server side so that the browser can handle the Cross-Origin request.
(I still tag it as LibGDX because this is an issue you will naturally encounter when porting your LibGDX code to GWT).

This website compiles the list of how to modify your server to handle such requests based on the technology you use: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

In my case, using Java on Google App Engine, on the server side I modified my HttpServletResponse's header as follow to handle the preflight processing:

```
public class MyClass extends HttpServlet {


@Override
    protected void doOptions(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        // pre-flight request processing
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, WHATEVER_PARAM_YOU_MAY_NEED_IN_YOUR_HEADER");

    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        /* IMPLEMENTATION */
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        resp.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
        resp.getWriter().append(MY_ANSWER_STRING);
        //out.println();
    }
}
```